# Matplotlib - get value of autoscale

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, autoscaling

Is there a possibility to read the scale of the axis which are set by autoscale?

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid(True)

fig = plt.gcf()

plt.show()
```

I want to get the scale of the x and the y axis. In this case it would be 0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the plotting, you can do

```
# calculate x scale
ax = fig.gca()
foo = ax.get_xmajorticklabels()
bar = [float(foo[i].get_text()) for i in range(len(foo))] 
scale_x = bar[1]-bar[0]

# calculate y scale
foo = ax.get_ymajorticklabels()
bar = [float(foo[i].get_text()) for i in range(len(foo))] 
scale_y = bar[1]-bar[0]

print scale_x, scale_y
```

This only works after `plt.show()` is called (unclear to me, maybe a separate question for SO), but it works. Just append those lines to your script.